# The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/ftps could not be found

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I tried updating the packages, using:

```
sudo apt update
```

but I get the error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/ftps could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-ftps installed?
```

[image]

Comment: In the future, please post terminal output as a code block instead of as a picture,  Text is searchable and more accessible compared to pictures.

Answer (score 0):

The entry you have in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or one of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` contains an FTP URL (`ftp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`), but APT doesn't have the package installed to deal with FTP or FTPS URLs.

The easiest thing to do in this case is switch to an HTTPS URL, if that's possible, or an HTTP URL, if it's not.  FTP is an older protocol that has some undesirable problems, such as firewall traversal issues, compatibility problems with TLS support, and a lack of implementation for common machine-readable formats.  As a result, HTTPS (or SFTP) is generally better in almost all cases, including this one.

You also seem to have some other problems in your output, including using a PPA for gnome-terminator that appears not to be properly configured (or doesn't exist) and a lack of a key for your Unifi output.  I'd remove the former and find the key for the latter somewhere on the Ubiquiti website and add it with `sudo apt-key add`.